# Site-to-Site VPN with Sophos XG using tunnel interface

Tags: vpn, ipsec, tunnel, site-to-site, sophos

So I have configured a Sophos XG site-to-site vpn according to this document:﻿
https://docs.sophos.com/nsg/sophos-firewall/18.0/Help/en-us/webhelp/onlinehelp/nsg/sfos/learningContent/VPNCreateRouteBasedVPN.html

But I am stuck with the following problem:
SiteA: Branchoffice, LAN 192.168.198.0/24
SiteB: Headoffice, LAN 172.30.0.0/24
If I ping from Site-A to Site-B, tcpdump on Sophos-A shows this while ping goes through:

```
18:53:04.059527 Port1, IN: IP 192.168.198.244 > 172.30.0.3: ICMP echo request, id 46946, seq 0, length 64
18:53:04.059737 xfrm1, OUT: IP 192.168.198.244 > 172.30.0.3: ICMP echo request, id 46946, seq 0, length 64
18:53:04.069119 xfrm1, IN: IP 172.30.0.3 > 192.168.198.244: ICMP echo reply, id 46946, seq 0, length 64
18:53:04.069193 Port1, OUT: IP 172.30.0.3 > 192.168.198.244: ICMP echo reply, id 46946, seq 0, length 64
```

If I ping from Site-B to Site-A, tcpdump records the following on Sophos-B and ping does not go through:

```
18:53:21.509216 Port4, IN: IP 172.30.0.3 > 192.168.198.244: ICMP echo request, id 2025, seq 1, length 64
18:53:21.509354 xfrm1, OUT: IP >WAN-IP< > 192.168.198.244: ICMP echo request, id 2025, seq 1, length 64
```

How come that from Site-A to B it goes `xfrm1, OUT: IP 192.168.198.244` (as expected) while from Site-B to A it's `xfrm1, OUT: IP >WAN-IP<`

I just don't get why it uses the WAN-IP from B to A but the other way round it takes the  correct path?

Cheerz

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.
The Sophos Base license (includes S2S-VPN functionality) has been temporarily suspended. Now everything works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Site B is missing the route for 192.168.198.0/24 pointing into the tunnel. Without it, the packet leaks out to WAN.

You need to either set up a static route or configure OSPF between the firewalls (requires 'always-on' VPN).